# why wordpress is not taking encrypted string in parameter as it is

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a curl function and in header i have passed few parameters. one parameter must be encrypted. so i have used AES algorithm to encrpt that string parameter. after encryption it contains some special character, number. when i send a request wordpress doesn't take the string parameter as it is to send the request.

Same piece of code working fine outside the wordpress but in wordpress due to special char its giving me the error.

is there any utf setting i need to do. so that wordpress will take the parameter as it is.

```
<?phperror_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);class AES{ const M_CBC = 'cbc';
 const M_CFB = 'cfb';
 const M_ECB = 'ecb';
 const M_NOFB = 'nofb';
 const M_OFB = 'ofb';
 const M_STREAM = 'stream';
 protected $_key;
 protected $cipher;
 protected $data;
 protected $mode;
 protected $IV;
 /** * * @param type $data * @param type $key * @param type $blockSize * @param type $mode */
 function __construct($data = null, $key = null, $blockSize = null, $mode = null)
 { $this->setData($data);
 $this->setBlockSize($blockSize);
 $this->setKey($key);
 $this->setMode($mode);
 $this->setIV("");
 }
 /** *  * @param type $data */
 public function setData($data)
 {
 $this->data = $data;
 } 
 /** *  * @param type $key */
 public function setKey($key)
 {
 $this->_key = $key;
 }
 /** *  * @param type $blockSize */
 public function setBlockSize($blockSize)
 {
 switch ($blockSize)
 {
 case 128: $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
 break;
 case 192: $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192;
 break;
 case 256: $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
 break;
 }
 }


 /** *  * @param type $mode */
 public function setMode($mode)
 {
 switch ($mode)
 {
 case AES::M_CBC: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
 break;
 case AES::M_CFB: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CFB;
 break;
 case AES::M_ECB: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
 break;
 case AES::M_NOFB: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB;
 break;
 case AES::M_OFB: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_OFB;
 break;
 case AES::M_STREAM: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM;
 break;
 default: $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
 break;
 }
 } 


 /** *  * @return boolean */
 public function validateParams()
 {
 if ($this->data != null && $this->_key != null && $this->cipher != null)
 {
 return true;
 } 
 else
 {
 return FALSE;
 }
 }

 public function setIV($IV)
 {
 $this->IV = $IV;
 } 
 protected function getIV()
 {
 if ($this->IV == "")
 {
 $this->IV = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->mode), MCRYPT_RAND);
 $this->IV = mb_convert_encoding($this->IV,'UTF-8');
 }
 return $this->IV;
 } 



 /** * @return type * @throws Exception */  
 public function encrypt()
 {
 if ($this->validateParams())
 {
 $block = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
 $padding = $block - (strlen($this->data) % $block);
 $this->data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
 return trim(base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( $this->cipher, $this->_key, $this->data, $this->mode, $this->getIV())));
 } 
 else 
 { 
 throw new Exception('Invalid params!');
 }
 } 


 /** *  * @return type * @throws Exception */ 
 public function decrypt()
 {
 if ($this->validateParams())
 {
 return trim(mcrypt_decrypt( $this->cipher, $this->_key, base64_decode($this->data), $this->mode, $this->getIV()));
 }
 else 
 { throw new Exception('Invalid params!');
 }
 } 
 }
 ?><?php date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
 $t = microtime(true);
 $sig_data= date('Y-m-d H:i:s.', substr($t, 0, -3)) . substr($t,-3);


 /// Add your API Key
 $api_key='71ae815b-6075-XXXXX-a12d7878bf47'; 
 /// Add your API Secret
 $private_key='079499d582934XXXXc4dbd12645e4581';
 $mode='cbc';
 $blockSize = 128;
 /// Generate the Signature
 $aes = new AES($sig_data, $private_key, $blockSize, $mode);
 $enc = $aes->encrypt();
 echo $enc;

 $en = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z]/', 'p', $enc);
 echo $en;

 /// Call the GetProducts Method
 $url="https://api.omgpm.com/network/OMGNetworkApi.svc/v1.1/ProductFeeds/GetProductsByCategory?".http_build_query(array('AgencyID' => 95, 'AID' => 861823, 'MID' =>$mid, "CategoryKeyword" => $opt_category  ,"NumberOfRecords"=>10, 'MinPrice' => 5000000, 'MaxPrice' => 99999999999, 'Currency' => 'INR', 'DiscountedOnly' => 'false', 'ProductSKU' => '', 'Key' => $api_key, 'Sig' => $en, 'SigData' => $sig_data));
 $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json","Accept: application/json","Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" );
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);print_r($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: How exactly are you generating the query string that you're passing to curl?

Comment: i have written the code as well. Its working fine outside of wordpress. In wordpress its showing authentication error because of sig data which is my encrypted signature and each time i request, this signature gets change. wordpress is not taking my  $enc parameter correctly.